# Syntax Error : Invalid Return in Suitescript

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, csv-import

Trying to implement a very simple script that will automate the process of importing CSV files.
When on the validation phase when trying to upload the below to Netsuite I get the error:

syntax error: invalid return

Any thoughts greatly appreciated. Code below

I have adjusted the position of the curly braces to the below but this did not resolve the problem. Sorry if this is novice stuff.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

require(['N/task',])

function execute(scriptContext){
var scriptTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT});
scriptTask.mappingId = 212; 
var f = file.load('SuiteScripts/Purchasing Update 2022.csv');
scriptTask.importFile = f;
var csvImportTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
};
return{
    execute:execute
    };
```

Comment: `return` on its own line returns `undefined` - make sure you put the `{` on the same line if thats the object you want to return

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried that and got the same error. So the line now reads
return{
 execute:execute
 };

Comment: The signature for the `require` function is incorrect.  You need to change the first line to `require(['N/task'], function (task) {` and move the closing parenthesis to the end (along with the closing brace for the callback/factory function).  In other words add `})` after the end of your `return` block.

Comment: Thanks @Krypton if I'm honest I did give that a go but then I got another error saying 'Syntax error: missing ) after argument list' and was pretty much back to square 1. Thank you, glad to know I am on the right track, just need to figure out where the missing ) goes.

Comment: TRY THIS:

 define( ['N/task'], function(task ) {

function execute(scriptContext){
var scriptTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT});
scriptTask.mappingId = 212; 
var f = file.load('SuiteScripts/Purchasing Update 2022.csv');
scriptTask.importFile = f;
var csvImportTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
};
return{
    execute:execute
    };
});

Comment: Thanks @wozzarvl That worked perfectly and this matter is now resolved, have a great weekend.